# No puedo hacer copia de directorio desde api de google drive

Tags: php, google-api

Tengo la siguiente situación: estoy tratando de hacer un movimiento interno dentro de mi Google Drive con php, desde la api y me envía el siguiente error:

> An error occurred: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global",
>   "reason": "cannotCopyFile", "message": "This file cannot be copied by
>   the user." } ], "code": 403, "message": "This file cannot be copied by
>   the user." } }

Uso otras funciones, que si me trabajan sin problema como es crear un directorio, buscar el directorio así como subir los archivos al directorio. El token y las credenciales que estoy usando es el mismo para todo. A continuación les dejo el código de la función que estoy usando para hacer la copia para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Gracias

**Función**

```
    public function renameFile($service, $fileId, $newTitle)
{
    try {
        $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile($newTitle);

        $updatedFile = $service->files->copy($fileId, $file, array(
            'fields' => 'title'
        ));
        return $updatedFile;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**Array $newTitle**

```
    $newTitle =  array(
       'title' => 'titulo del directorio',
        'parents' => array('folder parents')
     );
```

Comment: Probablemente es un problema de permisos. Te recomiendo intentar copiar diferentes directorios, especialmente directorios que hayas creado con la cuenta que está autenticada para ver si te da el mismo error.

Comment: Revise lo que me comenta y todos los directorios los estoy usando par hacer la copia de un lugar a otro los cree con la misma cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de investigar a fondo, me di cuenta que Google Drive no tiene dicha funcionalidad. Si te vas a la interfaz de usuario de Google Drive y le das click derecho a un directorio, te darás cuenta que no aparece la opción **Hacer una copia**; Sin embargo, si le das click derecho a un archivo, esa opción sí está disponible. Es precisamente por eso que la acción no está disponible a través de la api tampoco.

Para lograr hacer una copia de un directorio, tendrás que:

1. Crear un nuevo directorio.
2. Listar todos los archivos del directorio viejo y hacerles una copia.
3. Actualizar las copias de los archivos para que el directorio padre sea el directorio que se creó en el paso uno.